# MySQL Multiple WHERE clauses output as separate columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table named **runs** with the following values.

| o_id | start_date |
| --- | --- |
| vi | 2021-12-30 03:16:22 |
| vi | 2021-12-30 03:18:50 |
| vi | 2021-12-30 05:07:18 |
| vi | 2021-12-30 05:19:05 |
| lo | 2021-12-30 03:30:01 |
| lo | 2021-12-30 03:32:04 |
| lo | 2021-12-30 04:23:12 |
| lo | 2021-12-30 05:11:24 |

I am trying to get an output of number of records per hour for each 'o_id'.

This sql query:

```
SELECT HOUR(start_date) AS HOUR,
COUNT('o_id') AS lo
FROM runs 
WHERE start_date BETWEEN str_to_date('2021-12-30 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H') AND str_to_date('2021-12-31 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H')
AND o_id = 'lo' 
GROUP BY HOUR(start_date) 
ORDER BY HOUR(start_date);
```

returns:

| HOUR | lo |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

And I would like to get a single query to return output like this:

| HOUR | lo | vi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |

I have tried:

```
SELECT HOUR(start_date) AS HOUR, COUNT('o_id') AS vi
        FROM runs W
        WHERE W.start_date BETWEEN str_to_date('2021-12-30 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H') 
        AND str_to_date('2021-12-31 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H') 
        AND W.o_id = 'vi'
UNION SELECT HOUR(start_date) AS HOUR, COUNT('o_id') AS lo
        FROM runs W
        WHERE W.start_date BETWEEN str_to_date('2021-12-30 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H') 
        AND str_to_date('2021-12-31 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H') 
        AND W.orchestrator_id = 'lo'
```

But I have obviously misunderstood how this works. I feel like I need to `Left Join`, but I can't think how to get it to work in my particular instance. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition inside your `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT HOUR(start_date) AS HOUR,
COUNT(case when o_id = 'lo' then 1 end) AS lo,
COUNT(case when o_id = 'vi' then 1 end) AS vi
FROM runs 
WHERE start_date BETWEEN str_to_date('2021-12-30 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H') AND str_to_date('2021-12-31 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H')
GROUP BY HOUR(start_date) 
ORDER BY HOUR(start_date);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea4e9ee439f7daff40c909ae5b024f25)

Comment: Amazing!!!! Thank you very much and happy new year.

Comment: @Prototype85 no problem, happy new year to you too buddy.

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION` query cannot solve your issue as it will combine the rows of 2 queries. To *"combine the columns"* you can use a `JOIN` but this should not be necessary for your use case.

Using the `SUM` function with a `CASE WHEN`:

```sql
SELECT HOUR(start_date) AS hour
    , SUM(CASE WHEN o_id = 'lo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lo
    , SUM(CASE WHEN o_id = 'vi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS vi
FROM runs
WHERE start_date BETWEEN str_to_date('2021-12-30 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H')
    AND str_to_date('2021-12-31 02', '%Y-%m-%d %H')
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour;
```

> I also replaced the `GROUP BY` & `ORDER BY` clauses to reuse the `hour` alias.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much and happy new year!

Comment: @Prototype85 you can upvote helpful answers and accept one that solves your issue, this is the "thank you" on SO ;-) Happy new year !